# 404 page not working for some routes in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-404, laravel-5.4

I have a route like this:

**web.php**

```
Route::get('post/{slug}', [
    'as'   => 'post.single',
    'uses' => 'PageController@getSingle',
]);
```

**PageController.php**

```
public function getSingle($slug)
{
    //some db stuff and returning an array to view
    return view('single', array('var1' => $var, 'var2' => $var2));
}
```

A post has a slug which is stored in the database. 
If a post exists with slug, example: `first-post`
Then the route `mysite.com/post/first-post` works as expected.
But if a post doesn't exists, example: `second-post`
Then the route `mysite.com/post/second-post` gives me an error:

```
**ErrorException**
Trying to get property of non-object
```

I want it to show a 404 error page (404 page is already configured)
`mysite.com/hellohello` gives and 404 page, so it's working as expected.

Any suggestion what should I do?

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't get you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eloquent has a neat `firstOrFail` method which either returns the first entity it finds, or if there is none throws an ModelNotFoundException which laravel converts to a 404 page.

```
public function getSingle($slug)
{
    $var = YourModel::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
    return view('single', compact('var'));
}
```

Comment: I was using this before `$post = Post::where('slug', $slug)->first();` changing `first()` to `firstOrFail()` solved my issue. Thanks. I  will mark you answer as accepted in 3 mins..

Answer (score 0):

I think you should update your function like:
And you can not close bracket in return view

```
public function getSingle($slug)
{

    //some db stuff and returning an array to view
    return view('single', array('var' => $var));
}
```

**UPDATE after OP change the question content**:

```
public function getSingle($slug)
{
    //some db stuff and returning an array to view
    $var = SOMEDBRESULT1;
    $var2 = SOMEDBRESULT2;
    return view('single', array('var1' => $var, 'var2' => $var2));
}
```

You can learn about how to [get first record](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent) from db with laravel 5.4.

Comment: I am passing multiple variables to the view from the array, I have updated my code in the question.

Comment: @Saurabh Make sure that you define $var and $var2 as per your updated question

Comment: @Saurabh: Also my answer is given based on your mistake from the your question code. Now you updated it with putting ')'.

Comment: Yes that was a typo in my question.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but the method by @tkausl worked for me. Moreover it's more elegant solution.